# filter on the basis of a value in an array in where

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, loopbackjs

I'm querying data, where the structure is something like this.

I have two models, **FoodDrinks** and **Cuisines**. They have many to many relation.

Now on the following query

```
{
   "filter": {
        "include": "cuisines"
   }
}
```

I am getting the following results.

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Biryani",
        "cuisines": [
             {
                 "id": 1,
                 "name": "Mughlai"
             },
             {
                 "id": 2,
                 "name": "North Indian"
             },
             {
                 "id": 3,
                 "name": "Afghani"
             }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Chhole Bhature",
        "cuisines": [
             {
                 "id": 2,
                 "name": "North Indian"
             }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Amritsari Naan",
        "cuisines": [
             {
                 "id": 2,
                 "name": "North Indian"
             },
             {
                 "id": 6,
                 "name": "Punjabi"
             },

        ]
    }
]
```

Now I want only those food drinks which have cuisines from the following array.

```
let cuisinesIDs = ["1", "2"]
```

> What will the following query for that?

Comment: Map your object and loop through cuisines

Comment: I have to write a loopback query. Can't insert JS programming here.

Comment: Something like this https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Include-filter.html#examples

Answer (score 0):

I guess something like the below should work:

```
{
   "filter": {
        "include": "cuisines"
   },
   "where": {
         "cuisines.id": {
             "inq": cuisinesIDs
         }
   }
}
```

Comment: It would work in the case where `cuisines` is an object not an array. Like 
 `"cuisines":  {"id": "1", "name": "Something"}`

Answer (score 0):

It might be the same answer as @Behrooz, but I would try:

```
{
   "filter": {
        "include": {
                relation: 'cuisines',
                scope: {
                    where: {
                       id: {inq: cuisinesIDs}
                    }
                }
            }
   }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this. In this case, it will filter the list of cuisines included with the foodDrinks list, but I want to filter the foodDrinks list.

Comment: I'm not sure at all, but I think you cannot do that in Loopbacksj. I would iterate over the foodDrinks and add a condition. Or maybe try a custom mongo query directly.

Comment: Yeah, my backend team also end up making a custom API for this.